# How can you use the moment generating function of a random variable to prove that the probability of its sample space is 1?

Tags: random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I'm told you can do so but I'm struggling to make the connection between the MGF and the probability of the sample space.

Comment: Isn't the probability of every sample space $1$?

Comment: MGF(0)=Total probability.  Should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have further context here, I don't see why you are proving this; the probability of the sample space being one is an axiom of probability.